# Firebase no funciona bien con la version descargada de Play Store

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Muy buenas a todos, estoy haciendo una pequeña app sencilla que es el típico quiz, y para aprender a usar Firebase CloudFiresote he incluido un ranking que guarda a los usuarios y los puntos de cada uno. La aplicación funciona perfectamente con el dispositivo virtual y con el dispositivo físico, ya que no muestra ningún error y muestra el ranking que se almacena en Firebase como se puede ver en las siguientes imagenes

[image: Ranking cuando la aplicación se prueba en el dispositivo virtual]
[image: Contenido de la colección Ranking]

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero cuando descargo la aplicación de Google Play, la aplicación funciona igual de bien pero no muestra el contenido del ranking, como se puede ver en la siguiente imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No pueden ser un problema de la clave SHA porque también leo las preguntas de Firebase Firestore y eso lo lee perfectamente sin ningún error. A continuación os muestro el código de como almaceno los usuarios

```
    public class HowPlayInfiniteFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText username;
    private TextView usernameText;
    private String usernameString;
    private String usernameID;
    private boolean  usernameSave = false;
    private InfiniteGameFragment infiniteGameFragment;
    private FirebaseFirestore database;



    public HowPlayInfiniteFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        assert savedInstanceState != null;

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_how_play_infinite, container, false);
        // Layout
        username = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextUser);
        username.setOnEditorActionListener(editorActionListener);
        usernameText = view.findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
        FloatingActionButton play = view.findViewById(R.id.playInfinite);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(usernameSave){
                    // Go InfiniteQuiz
                    infiniteGameFragment = new InfiniteGameFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.containerInfinteGame, infiniteGameFragment).commit();
                }
                else{
                    String text = getString(R.string.warningUsername);
                    StyleableToast.makeText(requireContext(),text,R.style.levelToast).show();
                }
            }
        });
        // Ya se escribió el nombre de usuario?

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext());
        usernameSave = data.getBoolean("usernameSave",false);
        usernameString = data.getString("username","");
        isUsernameSet();
    }

    private void isUsernameSet() {
        if(usernameSave){
            username.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            username.setEnabled(false);
            usernameText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            usernameText.setText(usernameString);
        }
    }


    /* Se llama cuando la aplicacion pasa de ser visible a ser parcialmente visible, pasa a onStop o onResume */
    public void saveOnFirebase()
    {
        // Se guardan los valores guardados (guardados tambien al cerrar la app)
        SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("usernameSave",usernameSave);
        editor.putString("username",usernameString);
        editor.putString("usernameID",usernameID);
        editor.apply();
    }



    private TextView.OnEditorActionListener editorActionListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                usernameString = username.getText().toString();
                // Se inicializa el nick en la base de datos
                compareUsername();
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private void compareUsername(){
        // Se comprueba que el nombre de usuario no esta repetido
        database.collection("ranking").whereEqualTo("username",usernameString)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if(queryDocumentSnapshots.size() > 0)
                            username.setError(getString(R.string.equalUsername));
                        else {
                            // Se añade el nombre de usuario
                            addUsername();
                        }
                    }

                });
    }

    private void addUsername() {
        int score = 0;
        Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
        user.put("username",usernameString);
        user.put("score",score);
        database.collection("ranking")
                .add(user)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                        // El nombre ya esta en la base de datos
                        usernameID = documentReference.getId();
                        usernameSave = true;
                        username.setEnabled(false);
                        username.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        usernameText.setText(usernameString);
                        usernameText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        saveOnFirebase();
                    }
                });
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    }
 }
```

A continuación, muestro el código que uso para leer de Firebase Firestore la colección Ranking:

```
public class RankingInfiniteFragment extends Fragment{

    private List<User> usersList;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection("ranking");
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    AdapterRanking adapterRanking;


    public RankingInfiniteFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ranking_infinite, container, false);
        usersList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_ranking);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        fillRankingList();
        adapterRanking = new AdapterRanking(usersList);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //que hacer despues de 10 segundos
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRanking);
            }
        }, DELAY);
        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                Intent MainActivity = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(MainActivity);
            }
        };
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(getViewLifecycleOwner(), callback);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapterRanking = new AdapterRanking(usersList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRanking);
    }

    private void fillRankingList() {

        collectionReference
                .orderBy("score", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(25)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        String username;
                        int score;

                        for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: queryDocumentSnapshots){

                            User user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);

                            username = user.getUsername();
                            score = user.getScore();

                            usersList.add(new User(username,score));
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                });
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    }
}
```

Y, como creo que puede ser algo de los permisos, muestro el contenido del archivo proguard-rules.pro

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class com.redpicklespy.videogamesquiz.HowPlayInfiniteFragment
-keep public class com.redpicklespy.videogamesquiz.RankingInfiniteFragment
-keep public class com.redpicklespy.videogamesquiz.*

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-keepattributes Signature

-keepclassmembers class com.redpicklespy.videogamesquiz.** {
  *;
}
```

Comment: Hola, te diria instala la apk debug en tu celular o crea un apk con firma e instalala en tu celular de esa manera tendras una version de "tienda" en tu celular :)

Comment: Hombre pero lo que yo quiero es que la versión que se descargue la gente funcione correctamente

Comment: Lo único por lo que no podría funcionar (estando seguro de que el código subido a Play Store lo probaste antes y funcionaba bien), es que en Firebase tengas alguna `Regla` que impida la lectura en el documento en cuestión. Revisa por tanto las `Reglas` en tu consola de Firebase. Ahora se ha incorporado también una opción `Monitorizar Reglas` que puede informarte quizá de posibles errores, problemas con permisos, etc.

Comment: Veo un pequeño error, puede ser o no el problema. Estás asumiendo que en 10 segundos se obtengan los resultados para actualizar tu adaptador. Cuando el resultado de `Scores` llega en el `onSuccess` en `RankingInfiniteFragment`, nunca actualizas la lista y esto hace que tu vista se quede en un estado pendiente de notificacion de cambios, ya que nunca notificas al adaptador que tu colección ha cambiado. Debes hacer `userList.clear();` antes del `for` y `adapterRanking.notifyDataSetChanged();` luego del `for`, sacar todo del Handler.postDelayed y eliminar todo del `onResume`.